# Change template progressDialog in AsyncTask for android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have a ProgressDialog running in a AsyncTask. I want to change the template progressDialog in AsyncTask for android.

Can somebody help me please, is this possible? Thank you in advance.

```
 class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{
  private ProgressDialog prgDialog;

  @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() 
  {
    prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(DataActivity.this);
    prgDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    prgDialog.setCancelable(false);
    prgDialog.show();
    super.onPreExecute();
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
   {
     // do some work like loading data
    return null;
   }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
  {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    prgDialog.cancel();
   // do some work when loading finish
  }
```

for example:
 [loading](https://cdn4.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/03/13/mobile-app-loading-screen-vector-19470313.jpg)

Comment: how do you want to change it? do you want it to be indeterminate or determinate?

Comment: I want just to change its appearance like an example.

Comment: so read `android.app.ProgressDialog` official API documentation - it allows you to set indeterminate drawable

Comment: I read the API documentation, but I did not find anything. Please explain it more?

Comment: I want change "SPINNER" animation and remove the message

Comment: as i said: you have to set indeterminate drawable - this is what you call `"SPINNER" animation`